# Использование AWS S3 совместно с React-приложением

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Пишу свое собственное приложение (облачное хранилище) на ReactJS при этом хочу получать данные, список бакетов и их содержимое непосредственно из существующего аккаунта Amazon. Документация у них слишком запутанная, уже испробовал несколько способов, но вот уже 2 дня никак не продвинусь. У меня уже есть credentials, хочу достучаться до своего хранилища, может кто подскажет как это сделать?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Используйте aws sdk и получайте нужную информацию. Только понимайте, что креды шарить нельзя, а т.к. reactjs это статический сайт, то где вы их будете хранить/получать.

Comment: То есть Amplify мне не нужен? Просто я воспринял так, что aws sdk она скорей под  node.js. Когда я ей пользовался, и отправлял запросы, то выдавало ошибку что запросы с локалхоста  запрещены cors'ом. У меня было 2 предположения - либо я неправильно настроил объект s3, где передавал креды и эндпоинт. Либо вообще в принципе неправильно использовал sdk. Хотя вроде делал по доке

Comment: для того, чтобы просто читать S3, вам достаточно SDK. Если вы собираетесь строить какое то приложение на основе AWS, это совершенно другой вопрос, там есть миллион инструментов и подходов.

Comment: По сути делаю копию S3 storage

Comment: Если пишете ответ конкретному человеку, пишите его ник вот так @КонстантинКаменский

Comment: для копии S3 вам SDK за глаза хватит. Как альтернатива можно в aws консоли юзера добавить, дать ему права на S3 только и пусть там ковыряется.

Comment: @tym32167 мне еще показалось странным, что метод listBuckets недоступен для исполнения в браузере, но пока мне для работы хватает listObjects, который уже возвращает содержимое бакета. Однако я уже израсходовал лимит запросов в месяц для своего аккаунта)

Comment: я бы не стал отправлять запросы из браузера в aws, а проксировал бы через свой бекенд. Так у вас будет больше контроля над тем, что происходит и вы сможете какие то свои ограничения наложить поверх ограничений aws.